# Second query within a query using results of first query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

The following select statement returns a list of students:

```
SELECT * FROM students2014 ORDER BY LastName
```

However, for each row I need to return data from another table (notes2014) to allow me to display the latest note for each student. The select statement would be as follows:

```
SELECT Note FROM notes2014 WHERE NoteStudent='$Student'
```

$Student indicates the ID for each student in the students2014 database. However this result only appears after the initial statement is queried.

So my question is, how can I run the second query within the first?

Comment: You probably need a join.

Answer (score 1):

Posted on behalf of the OP:

I've worked it out! Thank you for you help. I used left join in the end:

```
SELECT * FROM students2014
    LEFT JOIN notes2014 ON students2014.Student = notes2014.NoteStudent
    WHERE students2014.Consultant='$Consultant'
    ORDER BY students2014.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
Student, 
Note 
from 
students2014 s
INNER JOIN notes2014 n on Student = n.NoteStudent
ORDER BY lastName
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm totally lost with this. I've tried it and I'm getting absolutely nothing. What do you mean by studentId and student_ID? The column that indicates student ID is Student.

Comment: @PhilHowell: what is the studentId column in student2014?

Comment: It's called Student :) It's just an incremental value.

Answer (score 0):

you should query the data like this:

```
select students2014.*, notes2014.note from students2014, notes2014 where students2014.id = notes2014.NoteStudent
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! However the results exclude any students that don't presently have any corresponding notes... I need to display a complete list even if some students don't currently have a note.